# JQuery: How To Remove Element By Class If It Doesn't Contain Specified Word?

Tags: jquery

I'm using JQuery. While doing this works: "`$("div.g").remove(":contains('Opportunity')");"` When I try doing the opposite: `$("div.g:not").remove(":contains('Opportunity')")`, it doesn't work. I was curious to know where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply `:not` to the selector passed to `remove`:

```
$("div.g").remove(':not(:contains("Opportunity"))');
```

... or use `.not()` to filter the elements chain-passed to .remove():

```
$("div.g").not(':contains("Opportunity")').remove();
```

Here's a snippet showing both approaches in action:

```js
$('button.drop').click(() => {
  $("div.g").remove(':not(:contains("Opportunity"))');
}); 

$('button.drop_by_not').click(() => {
  $("div.g").not(':contains("Opportunity")').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="g">One</div>
<div class="g">Two</div>
<div class="g">Opportunity</div>
<div class="g">Opportunity Strikes</div>
<div class="g">Three Strikes</div>
<button class="drop">Drop!</button>
<button class="drop_by_not">Drop by Not!</button>
```

The way you wrote it originally (even if :not has been passed [correctly](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/), and not appended to the selector), it'd been applied to `div.g` elements instead, reverting `div.g` rule.